# Play Framework Bi-directional support including older browsers

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, signalr, atmosphere

I'm about to build a web application in Play Framework and I'll need to have bidirectional communication between the server and the browser.

For modern browsers I can use web sockets, but for older browsers I will need to use long polling. Is there a library that will abstract away this choice and choose whichever one is supported by the browser? Similar to SignalR in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Atmoshphere library is absolutely what I was looking for. https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

Two good options nowdays:

- SignalJ based on SignalR https://github.com/chanan/SignalJ using Akka and integrated in Play and with good integration with SignalJ web servers (based on .net)
- Atmoshphere library https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere that also supports Play integration and multitude of frameworks